# Why does the US Federal Election Commision currently not have quorum?

Tags: united-states, election, government, rule-of-law

It's been mentioned in many news pieces about Yang's [novel use of campaign funds](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/45601/is-yang-not-precluded-from-conducting-his-ubi-experiment-as-an-electoral-candi) that the US FEC cannot currently rule on it because it doesn't have quorum. So, why doesn't the FEC have quorum? It is a normal transition issue or some kind of (partisan) deadlock involved?